# How to change the collapse citation range delimiters in CSL?

Tags: csl

I want to change the cite collapsing style from something like [1-5] to [1~5]. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible, I'm afraid. CSL processors will always use an n-dash to collapse citation numbers and there's no term or attribute to determine the collapse delimiter.